# Wordpress admin panel framework weird layout on server side

Tags: theme-options, admin-bar, framework

I've called theme option panel via ***functions.php***, its layout appears well on localhost, but when I upload it to my hosting account via FTP panel columns floating itsel to the left. I think this is just a CSS issue but, I couldn't find for days at all, any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here are the screenshots

on server side
[image]

on localhost
[image]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the CSS to see what's different? This type of thing often happens if you have the sections floated and one of them grows just a little too big to fit within its expected area.

Comment: Yes I did and fixed it. I've changed size of a container then elements are floated smoothly,but I found this option panel very difficult to customize, I'll pick up another one instead. Its first dimension was 785, after changing to 786, it is fixed.

#of_container {
 margin: 15px;
 width: 786px;
 position:relative;
 z-index: 0;
}

Comment: Keep in mind if anyone else may use the theme it may be better to use percentages. Fixed-width relative-positioned elements can be a bear if you use a different sized monitor.

Comment: How we use these CSS commands then?

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/percent.html

Comment: Last night I'd stumbled upon this site, I'll check it again. Thank you.